# Python/html image comparison slider and video

Tags: python, html, image-comparison

I need to compare two images with a slider [see sample below] and then create a video with sliding from left to right. I also need to add labels (before and after). How can I do this is Python?

I did this in html [1](https://img-comparison-slider.sneas.io) but I cant create a video. HTML solution is also fine.

[image: sample image]